# Looking for a complete review of the BEC-BCS crossover

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I'm looking for comprehensive review of the BEC-BCS crossover, both from a theoretical point of view, and from a experimental one. Even something at textbook level, but exhaustive, would be OK, but I can't find this topic on the Condensed Matter Theory books I use (Altland, Annett).

In particular I know that some quantities related to the system are more BCS-like in the crossover, while some other are more BEC-like: also a theory vs. experiments review would be greatly useful.

Answer (score 2):

I recently started reading this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/BCS-BEC-Crossover-Unitary-Lecture-Physics/dp/3642219772](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642219772)

So far I like the organization and pace. But judging by the table of contents it appears to be very detailed and thorough. It is, however, a monograph. But the style is pretty close to a textbook. Plus it has around 150 references at the end of each chapter; I like that.